# jQuery: Select dropdown by HTML

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, special-characters, html-select, ampersand

I've written a jQuery function that allows me to select an option from a dropdown using the option's HTML.

```
$.fn.select = function( option ) {
    $(selector +  ' option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == option)
            $(selector).val($(this).val());
    });
    return this;
};
```

The function works perfectly fine, except with options that contain ampersands (`&`). In this case, it will fail to properly select the corresponding option.

Is there any way I can make this work?

I am aware that there already exists a `select` function for jQuery; however, it seems that my `select` function is able to overwrite the existing function.

Comment: could you provide a demo page or a working fiddle?

Comment: And what exactly is selector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working right with `&`, Whats the problem ?

Though replacing `&` with `&amp;` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

try replace `&` to `&amp;` and then compare them